# split column into new row for three column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I tried to using ;with tmp() and union all but still no luck via mssql.

This is my source

```
instance  |host   |servicename
DB,tomcat |abc,xyz|sap,java
null      |efg,ijn|D40,L90
```

And I would like to get the output like this

```
instance|host|servicename
DB      |abc |sap
Tomcat  |xyz |java
        |efg |D40
        |ijn |L90
```

Do you have any solution how to maka a relationize for this?

Comment: Is it always 2 or nothing? I mean, can you have a row with `abc,dei|a|b,c,d,e|`?

Comment: *"I tried to using `;with tmp()` and `union all`"* show us that attempt then. *(Also, `;` is a terminator, not a "beginninator". You should be terminating your statements with a `;`, not just starting statements with a `;` that require the **previous** statement to be terminated.)*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string

Comment: @Rindu Accept the ansewr

Comment: @Sreenu131it's not good courtesy to demand a user to accept your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Rindu Saving the data in comma separated form is a bad design

Comment: @Sreenu131 what if your answer is wrong? (I'm not saying it is, but it might be)

Comment: @ZoharPeled i am just trying to help him in that process i asked him to accept it.i didn't think the great experts like you ask me this question.its just matter of comment and its his choice

Comment: @Sreenu131 I'm far from being a great expert, however I do have some experience with SQL Server, and more importantly, with stackoverflow. Answering incomplete questions is one thing, expecting the OP to accept your answer while it was based (at least partially) on assumptions you made that are not necessarily correct - that's a different thing. IMHO, this question is not yet ready to receive an answer, let alone an answer that can be confidently trusted as solving the issue at hand. Too many details are missing in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp
;WITH CTE(instance  ,host   ,servicename)
AS
(
SELECT 'DB,tomcat' ,'abc,xyz','sap,java' UNION ALL
SELECT null      ,'efg,ijn','D40,L90'
)

SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY instance) AS Seq
        ,ISNULL(instance,'NA') AS instance
        ,Host
        ,servicename
 INTO #Temp FROM CTE

SELECT a.Seq
        ,Split.a.value('.','nvarchar(1000)') AS instance
        ,Split1.a.value('.','nvarchar(1000)') AS host
        ,Split2.a.value('.','nvarchar(1000)') AS servicename
FROM(
SELECT Seq
    ,CAST('<S>'+REPLACE(instance,',','</S><S>')+'</S>'  AS XML )AS instance
    ,CAST('<S>'+REPLACE(host,',','</S><S>')+'</S>'  AS XML )AS host
    ,CAST('<S>'+REPLACE(servicename,',','</S><S>')+'</S>'  AS XML )AS servicename
    FROM #Temp 
) As a
CROSS APPLY instance.nodes('S') AS Split(a)
CROSS APPLY host.nodes('S') AS Split1(a)
CROSS APPLY servicename.nodes('S') AS Split2(a)
ORDER BY seq
```